# How to add GPS data to video (geotag it)?

Tags: metadata, gps, exif

I want to publish/upload 360 panoramas via Google Streetview Studio. To do this I'm required to have:

1. Geotagged video exported from the camera
2. .GPX file

I have geotagged 360 panoramas instead of the video captured by Trimble MX7 device.
Therefore, I created .mp4 video out of these panoramas with 1 fps using Blender. I also have GPX file.
It appears that the output video file isn't geotagged even though panoramas were geotagged.
How can I geotag the video?
Video Geotagger tool seemed to be the solution but didn't work. It said duration was too long and I couldn't fix the issue.
Btw duration of the video I created is 28 mins with 8000x4000 res and ~6gb in size.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the date and time of your first footage.

Open your gpx file with a text editor and locate the first geotagging line. Here you find the start date and time

```
<time>yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ</time>
```

Install Exiftool and launch it inside the folder of your video file by doing this:

Linux: Right click inside the folder and select Terminal and then type the exiftool command.

Windows: Inside the folder type in the address bar cmd and hit enter then type the exiftool command and hit enter.

A simple exiftool command to change your video creation date is:

```
exiftool -CreateDate="yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss" yourvideoname.extension
```

To change all dates:

```
exiftool -Time:All="yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss" yourvideoname.extension
```

To add the equirectangular exif data so your video can be played on the 360 softwares. Add the metadata also by exiftool:

```
exiftool -XMP-GSpherical:Spherical="true" -XMP-GSpherical:Stitched="true" -XMP-GSpherical:StitchingSoftware=SoftwareName -XMP-GSpherical:ProjectionType=equirectangular yourvideoname.extension
```

If your file is larger than 1GB start every exiftool command line with this:

```
exiftool -api largefilesupport=1
```

You add as many arguments as you want inside a single exiftool command line. After finishing the exiftool will create a new video file with the applied changes and rename your original as yourvideoname.extension_original

Combine the gpx files of your photo panoramas into a single gpx file by following their chronological order.

The combined gpx file should finally look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" version="1.1" creator="TrackerDeviceManufacturer" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd ">
    <metadata>
        <name>GpxFileName</name>
        <keywords>TrackerDevice</keywords>
    </metadata>
    <trk>
        <name><![CDATA[Tracked with TrackerDeviceName]]></name>
        <trkseg>
            <trkpt lat="12.348678" lon="-12.345678">
                <ele>123.456789123</ele>
                <time>2023-11-15T13:55:20Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="12.348678" lon="-12.345678">
                <ele>123.456789123</ele>
                <time>2023-11-15T13:56:00Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="12.348678" lon="-12.345678">
                <ele>123.456789123</ele>
                <time>2023-11-15T13:57:25Z</time>
            </trkpt>
        </trkseg>
    </trk>
</gpx>
```

Notice that every panorma's gpx data is put in between trkpt tags.

Now you upload your new video and the combined gpx file to GSV and happy geotagging and street viewing!